# inline definition/declaration in C

Tags: c, gcc, inline

The C Standard has an example from 6.7.4 section:

```c
inline double fahr(double t)
{
    return (9.0 * t) / 5.0 + 32.0; 
}
inline double cels(double t)
{
    return (5.0 * (t - 32.0)) / 9.0;
}
extern double fahr(double); // creates an external definition
double convert(int is_fahr, double temp)
{
    /* A translator may perform inline substitution */
    return is_fahr ? cels(temp) : fahr(temp);
}
```

And next it says:

> Because cels has external linkage and is referenced, an external definition has to appear in another translation unit.

What does exactly mean *in another translation unit*?

I tried such an example:

```c
inline int foo() {
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  return foo();
}
```

As the Standard says `foo` should have external definition in another TU, but what does this mean? Why I'm getting the following error:

```
$ gcc main.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccsaje5J.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I add the external definition at the top of the source file (but this is the same TU):

```c
int foo();

inline int foo() {
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  return foo();
}
```

The error goes away. Why is it so, and is it necessary to have an external declaration in the same file?

Comment: That's a *declaration*, not a *definition*.

Comment: Your example doesn't follow the the example from the standard. You don't have an `extern` declaration in `main.c`. And you don't ***define*** (implement) the function in `foo.c`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, mentioned example doesn't have an external definition/declaration here for `cels`. Yes, I didn't implement `foo`, that's what I want - use inline function `foo` from `main.c`, how should I modify this code to achive this?

Comment: If I try to compile only `main.c` I'll get the same error, I want to use `foo` from `main.c` and implement it there too. When I add an external definition into `main.c` like `int foo();` at the top of `main.c` it works, but why should I do it? What's the reason?

Comment: Don't use the `inline` keyword? It's only a *hint* for the compiler, and the compiler is allowed to totally disregard the "hint" and not inline your function anyway. And the compiler can inline any function, even those *not* marked with `inline`. So if it gives you trouble, just don't use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, indeed compiler will inline any function if it decides that this function may be inlined with some optimizations like `-O2` or so. Not using `inline` keyword does not give me the knowledge why the code above does not work.... And this is  exactly what I want to

Comment: Fair point. You know the workaround, but want to know the reason you need to work around it. :)

Comment: @k1r1t0 because it is not `static` and has no external linkage and it cannot be inlined. https://godbolt.org/z/WTKqqo43v Compiler and linker have no way of calling it

Comment: @0___________, you mean that if I want to call this function (that has external linkage) from another TU, a compiler has no way to figure out where should it call the function from, because it marked `inline`?

Comment: @k1r1t0 because of `inline` it does not have an external linkage by definition. BTW IMO it is a bug but gcc works this way

Comment: @0___________, `clang` works the same way